# Python :AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, may I ask why does my code not work?

Question: square every digit of a number and concatenate them

```
Input:9119
Output:811181
```

my code:

```
def square_digits(num):
    num=str(num)
    newnum=""
    for i in num:
        newnum.append(i**2)
    return int(newnum)
```

why does it state that:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Just for fun a one-liner: `return int(''.join((str(int(c)**2) for c in str(num))))`

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed not use append on a string, but you can add to it. Make sure to manage your varibale types. `i` is a string and that doesn't support the `**` operator. You need to convert i to int, use ** and then convert the result back to str to add it to newnum.

```
def square_digits(num):
    num=str(num)
    newnum=""
    for i in num:
        newnum += str(int(i)**2)
    return int(newnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `append` on variables that are of the `str` type.
If you want to concatenate strings use `join` or the `+=` operator. Remember that you have to transform the int into a str using `str()`

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, you want to take an integer and return another integer, which is the result of the concatenation of all individual numbers, after squaring each one of them.

The error message you get is because, the `append` method, in the way that you are trying to use it, it should be a `list`, but you are applying it to a string (`str`)

Your code should be like this:

```
def square_digits(input_int):
    input_str=str(input_int)
    squared_nums=[]
    for each_char in input_str:
        squared_nums.append(int(each_char)**2)
    output = ''.join([str(num) for num in squared_nums])
    return int(output)
square_digits(9119)
```